# Python Scrapy: Login to a website then scrape

Tags: python, html, authentication, scrapy

I am trying something new for practicing web scraping. I am trying to login in a website and then scrape specific items.

I have constructed this code for this purpose, but it is not working. I am using `scrapy.FormRequest` to login, and using what I read from the documentation so  far, I have the following code setup:

```
class HomelyspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "homelyspider"
    allowed_domains = ["homely.com.au"]
    start_urls = ['https://homely.com.au/']

    def parse(self, response):
    
             yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
                response,
                formxpath='.//div[@class="Modal-body"]/form',
                formdata={
                    'usernameOrEmail': 'myusername',             
                    'password': 'mypassword',
                },
                clickdata = { "type": "Submit" },
                callback=self.after_login
            )
    def after_login(self, response):
            "DO SCRAPING NOW"
```

**Login page HTML**:

```
   <div class="Auth Auth--modal">
    <div class="signin ">
        <div class="Modal-header">
            <h1 class="Modal-title">Sign in</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="Modal-body">
            <p class="subtitle">Instant sign in with Facebook or Google:</p><a class="Button Button--icon Button--facebook small-12" href="/authentication/redirect/Facebook"><span role="presentation" class="icon-wrapper"><svg class="icon icon-facebook"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-facebook"></use></svg></span><span class="label">Continue with Facebook</span></a><a class="Button Button--icon Button--google small-12" href="/authentication/redirect/Google"><span role="presentation" class="icon-wrapper"><svg class="icon icon-google"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-google"></use></svg></span><span class="label">Continue with Google</span></a>
            <p>or using your email:</p>
            <form>
                <label class="">
                    <input type="text" aria-label="Email or Username" required="" pattern="^[^-\s].+" title="Please enter a valid value" name="usernameOrEmail" placeholder="Email or Username" class="FormControl" value="">
                </label>
                <label class="">
                    <input type="password" aria-label="Password" required="" pattern="^[^-\s].+" title="Please enter a valid value" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="FormControl">
                </label>
                <button class="Button Button--alt small-12" type="submit"><span class="Button-message">Sign In</span>
                </button>
            </form>
            <p class="forgotten">
                <button class="ButtonLink">Forgot Password?</button>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="Modal-line"></div>
        <div class="Modal-footer">
            <p>
                <!-- react-text: 71 -->Not yet a member?
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <button class="ButtonLink">Register with Homely</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know this is irrelevant because the from is in the page, but still I am showing the steps and the elements with the links provided.

This is the **main page** where I have to click **Sign In**:

[image]

[image]

Then comes the **Sign In popup** that contains the form code that I have previously provided:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? From what I understand from the **[scrapy DOCs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/)**, my scrapy form request code should work, right?

Answer (score 0):

ValueError: No  element found in <200 https://www.homely.com.au/>
it does not find the form...

Comment: i can see that too .. can you tell why ? the form xpath is ok

Comment: no not really since i get errors too when using xpath dont kno why

Comment: i see the problem now the form does not shows until i click on the sign in button